# Deleting Multiple Rows from an Access Database

Tags: c#, arrays, ms-access

I want to delete multiple records from access database using array.
The array is loaded dynamically from file names.

Then i query the database, and see if the database column values are matching with the array values, if not then delete it, if matches then do not delete it.

the problem is that:
Following is the code that deletes all records irrespective of the where in Condition.

```
arrays = Directory.GetFiles(sdira, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
    fnames.AddRange(arrays); 

    here I have use also for loop but that also didnt help me out :( like for(int u = 0; u < arrays.length; u++) { oledbcommand sqlcmd = new oledbcommand ("delete from table1 where name not in ("'+arrays[u]+"')",sqlconnection);
   I am using this one currently foreach(string name in arrays)
   {
       OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from table1 where name not in ('" + name + "')", sqlconnection);
       sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                                  }`
```

Comment: Hi Safi, Can you post some code? it sounds like to need to check String.IsNullOrEmpty to ensure there is a value in the array

Comment: Showing more code would help identify the problem.

Comment: string[] names = { " 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg','c.jpg','j.jpg' "};
             
 for (int j = 0; j<names.Length; j++)
              {
OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from table1 where name not in (" + names[j] + ")", sqlconnection);
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                
            }

Comment: the above code is to delete records which do not match the array i.e name.

Comment: The non-working code would probably be more interesting for everyone...

Comment: your string is not reading in 4 entries, its reading one entry of string names = " 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg','c.jpg','j.jpg' " it should be string[] names = { "a.jpg", "b.jpg","c.jpg","j.jpg" };

Comment: @safi: When adding code to your question, you can edit and add it to the original question (instead of in a comment as you've done above). Adding code in the original question not only makes it easier to find, but it allows you to format it to make it more clear as well.

Comment: @ manatherin, the above code is working perfectly, but if change the array to a load dynamically i.e from system file name like (c:/files/images/) then the whole table is deleted :(

Comment: If you can post the code that is reading the file names or initializing values in names array, we would be able to help you better.

Comment: string [] lok = {};  foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdira))
                {
         foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*"))
                    {
       comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
          int j = 0;
     lok[j++] = Path.GetFileName(f); }                                           for(int u = 0 ; u<lok.Length; u++)
                          {
OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from table1 where name not in (" +lok[u]+")", sqlconnection);
                                    
           sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                          }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem is that your code is confusing.

```
string [] a = {"" 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg' "}
```

First, you have double " in the beginning,should only be one.

```
string [] a = {" 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg' "}
```

Then this created a string array with one element,

```
a[0] = "'a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg'";
```

Then you do a foreach on this which natuarly ony executes once resulting in this query:

```
delete from table1     where name not in ('a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg')
```

But when you load the array dynamically you probably get this array

```
a[0] = 'a.jpg';
a[1] = 'b.jpg';
a[1] = 'c.jpg';
```

which will execute 3 times in the foreach resulting in the following 3 queries

```
delete from table1     where name not in ('a.jpg')
delete from table1     where name not in ('b.jpg')
delete from table1     where name not in ('c.jpg')
```

After the second one the table will be empty.

You should try this instead:

```
string[] names = { "a.jpg", "b.jpg","c.jpg","j.jpg" };
string allNames = "'" + String.Join("','", names) + "'";

OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from table1  where name not in (" + allNames + ")", sqlconnection); 
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Where names is created dynamically ofcause and this will result in the following query matching your test:

```
delete from table1     where name not in ('a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg')
```

My preferred way to dynamically fill an array is to use a list instead as a pure array is fixed in size and any change needs to create a new array.

You can loop over a list as eacy as an array.

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
//or user var keyword
var names = new List<string>();
```

Then just use add method to add elements, loop this as needed.

```
names.Add(filename);
```

Then for the concatenation:

```
string allNames = "'" + String.Join("','", names.ToArray()) + "'";
```

And you are done.

Or you could use

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.jpg");
string[] names = filePaths.ToList().ConvertAll(n => n.Substring(n.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @ David Martensson, I like your suggestion and appreciate your effort for taking time to provide a good solution. in your case code, suppose my string [] a= {}, and i want to fill this array with images file names from a directory let say c:/images/, then what i need to do? Thanks

Comment: Se my addition in the end for creating the array.

Comment: @ David Martensson, |THanks alot for this i did solve the problem, your soultion did help me to get out of the trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

posting my comment as a answer

your string is not reading in 4 entries, its reading one entry of

```
string names = " 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg','c.jpg','j.jpg' ";
```

it should be

```
string[] names = { "a.jpg", "b.jpg","c.jpg","j.jpg" };
```

before your for each had a count of 1 now it should have a count of 4 with the actual values

Edit:
Not a lot of effort in this solution i must admit but if you want dynamic input could do something like:

```
    string name = " 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg','c.jpg','j.jpg' ";
    string[] names = name.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim(' ').Trim('\'')).ToArray();
```

will update later if i get the change as the trims are not good atm

For populating it, if you want it as enumerable a example could be something like

```
IEnumerable<string> filelocations = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x));
```

or for string array

```
string [] lok = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: string[] lok ={} ;                                                       foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*"))
                    {    lok[j++] = Path.GetFileName(f); }

Comment: can you tell how can i get all the file names into an array, i have the loop and the array, but cant get the array to be fill up with it, i think the problem is with filling the array from the files names.

Comment: @safi: updated for how to read out file names as string array where source directory = location e.g. string sourceDirectory = "c:\\images\\";

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're either not reading the file correctly or the file is empty.  You should be checking the array to make sure it's not empty before running the operation against the database.  If the array is empty, it SHOULD delete everything in the database as there are no matches.

Comment: @ telos: I read the file correctly, but the problem is with getting the values off the array :(

Comment: can you tell how can i get all the file names into an array, i have the loop and the array, but cant get the array to be fill up with it, i think the problem is with filling the array from the files names. – safi 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the array like this:

```
string[] names = { "a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg", "j.jpg" };
```

the way you are defining the array it contains only one value:

```
" 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg','c.jpg','j.jpg' "
```

Comment: @ the villageLdiot:   the code work, but the problem is that i do not want static string values in the array names, i define array like this, String [] names; and then populate it via for loop and insert into the array the file names.

Comment: If you don't want to define an array of a set length, use a List<string> instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your comment will delete any files not matching the first file. that would be all non 'a.jpg' files. The next iteration will delete all files that don't match 'b.jpg' which would be 'a.jpg'. This results in an empty table. **Edit:** The array declaration you have generates a good `IN` clause when you do it manually, but when you're getting a list of filenames, you're not generating this same string.

You need to perform a join on the array to generate a single string for your where clause that way the where clause includes all files. Your ultimate where clause should look like:

```
where name not in ('a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg')
```

Right now you have:

```
where name not in ('a.jpg')
```

... next iteration

```
where name not in ('b.jpg')
```

Also, be mindful that `IN` operations are expensive and the longer the array is the faster the query grows.

Comment: yes, i post that code as this query work with static array, but with dynamic array, it dont :(, i have post the code you can see that how i am dooing it dynamically :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list if you don't want to create a static sized array

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("a.jpg");
names.Add("b.jpg");
names.Add("c.jpg");


foreach (string name in names)
{
   OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand("delete from table1 
   where name not in (" + name + ")", 
   sqlconnection); 
   sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: As discussed in the other answers you may want to change your sql query