# How do I create a list of filenames from a folder in C#

Tags: c#

I got a problem when i want to populate an array with the file names.

the code is:

```
 string [] arrays= {};
 String sdira= "path of the directory";

 foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdira))
 {

   foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*"))`enter code here`
   {
     int j = 0;

     array[j++] = path.getfiles(f);
   }

 }
```

when i loop through array, the array contains nothing :(
so how to fill the array in this case? 
or any better solution :)

Comment: Please place code in a `code` block to make it easier to read. You can do that by indenting each line by at least four spaces.

Comment: fixed the code formatting, now to check on the problem...

Comment: It was `Directory.GetFiles(d, ".")`?? That could also cause a problem

Comment: Your question title should give people an idea of what you are asking about. Treating it as a tag list is not helpful.

Comment: @ To all who reads the post: I am sorry about the code formating, if i understand Vlad correctly, so I have to to press four times spaces and then enter my code, i am asking for future clarification,

Comment: @Josefvz:  its directory.getfiles(d,*.*) :)

Comment: @safi: that will work for marking as code, alternatively you can select the code sections and press the button with the picture of 2 curly brackets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution as posted on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794498/c-array-access/4794613#4794613). This eliminates the need to loop at all

```
string [] arrays;
String sdira= "path of the directory";

arrays =  Directory.GetFiles(sdira, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
```

could also do

```
arrays = Directory.GetFiles(sdira, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => (Path.GetExtension(s).ToLower() == extensionType)).ToArray();
```

if you want to only get say .jpg (seemed indicated in your other question) the extensionType = ".jpg"

Comment: @ Manatherin, Well I am really impressed by your smart code. This work very efficiently. :) thanks alot

Answer (score 6):

you are resetting j to 0 at the begning of each iteration of the loop.

How about this:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
String sdira = "path of the directory";

foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdira)) {

    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*")) {
       files.Add(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if i define it out side the post still , it get just one value,in the array and the rest of the array is empty.

Comment: You need to initialize the array size, or use a List collection to add elements to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the length of the array before filling it.

```
string[] array = new string[16]; // this will create an arrray of length 16.
```

In your case, you will need to initialize the length of the array to the amount of files in the directory.

In case you want to search the directories recursively, you will be better off using a list instead of an array.

Comment: I have define now the array length, but still it just get one value from the result and the rest of the array is empty :(

Comment: That's because you were resetting the j variable each round in the loop. I did not see that at first. But I would recommend you to use Chris Kooken's solution with a list.

Comment: true but you could do it all in a single line like `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(optimizedFiles, "*.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an array you should better use a `List<string>`. The array has a fixed length, but you do not know the number of files, before you query all directories.

```
var files = new List<string>(); 
string sdira= "path of the directory"; 
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdira)) {   
    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*"));   
}

// To use
foreach(string file in files) { }
string file2 = files[2]; 
// or convert to array
string[] arrays = files.ToArray();

// Or to use as datasource    
comboBox1.DataSource = files;
```

Comment: @ GVS, in this case how to use List, give me a clue :)

Comment: I was adding the code to fill the list. You can use the List<string> (I named it files, seems better to me), just like an array. Or you can convert to to an array.

Comment: @GvS: Thanks I am trying this, and let I hope this will work for me.

Comment: I try this but not all the file in the directory are listed. like if there are 300 files, only 10 are displyed, to view that files were added succeffuly to the list, i do like this: combo1.datasoure= list.

Comment: foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdira))
    {
 foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*"))
                    {filename.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
comboBox1.DataSource = filename; } }

Comment: You should set the datasource, when you leave the outer foreach. I updated my example.

Comment: in the code you i did right after the filename, to this next is combo1.datasoure = filename, isnt it the correct?

Comment: I think it's too early. Your list of files is not filled completly yet.

Comment: @GVS, I am back into business sorry i was away for some reasons :), In your code you mention Line 4, Path.GetFiles(which isnt right here) because system gives error plus, it accept only two arguments :), So how you get it here?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you don't know the size of the array you are using I think you'd be much better off using a generic collection like `List<T>`, i.e.

```
 List<string> Filenames = List<string>();
 String sdira= "path of the directory";

 foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdira))
 {
   foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*"))
   {
       Filenames.Add(f);
   }
 }
```

Comment: @ Lazarus: Thanks I am trying this, and let I hope this will work for me.

Comment: I try this but not all the file in the directory are listed. like if there are 300 files, only 10 are displyed, to view that files were added succeffuly to the list, i do like this: combo1.datasoure= list.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a chicken and egg thing going on here, when you create your `arrays` object you need to specify the size of the array.  However you can't do that until you have looked in the directories.  Running over the directory list twice would be a bad idea.

I would suggest that you use a `System.Collections.Generic.List` object as an intermediary as this negates the need to specify the size of the initial string array, you can then convert that to your string array (in fact you may not need to do that at all depending on what you app is doing with your `arrays` object.  For example:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> filesList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
string path = @"c:\my\directory\";

foreach (string directory in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory))
    {
        filesList.Add(file);
    }
}

string[] filesArray = filesList.ToArray();
```

EDIT : Updated code sample with a defensive directory exists check and also retrieval of files from the base directory:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> filesList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
string path = @"c:\my\directory\";

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
{
    //Get files for the base path
    string[] baseDirectoryFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
    filesList.AddRange(baseDirectoryFiles);

    // Get files in subdirectories (first level) of base path
    foreach (string directory in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        string[] directoryFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory);
        filesList.AddRange(directoryFiles);
    }

    string[] filesArray = filesList.ToArray();
}
else
{
    //Your directory was not found on the filesystem
    //handle as appropriate
}
```

This will get all files in the base directory and the first level of sub directories, it will not however get file names from sub directories of sub directories.  To support that you should look at a recursive method.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample that show how to do this recursively, and therefore get all files from all directories regardless of depth:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
    GetFileNames(@"C:\my\base\directory", fileNames);
}

private void GetFileNames(string directory, List<string> files)
{
    files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory));

    foreach(string subDirectory in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
    {
        GetFileNames(subDirectory, files);
    }
}
```

Comment: using this , if there are suppose 100 files in the directory, so i get only 10 :( ?

Comment: @ Mr eyes:  
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sdira))
                {

                    
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*"))
                    {            filename.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
                        comboBox1.DataSource = filename;      } }

Comment: The sample above will only pick up files in sub directories of 'c:\my\directory\' so any files in that directory will not be included in the array.  Do you also need files in the root directory?

Comment: Updated answer with a solution to get files from the base directory.

Comment: @MrEyes, Thanks and how to use Recursive, method, is it the same as i have used in sample code?

Comment: @Mr Eyes:if there are 300 files, only 10 are displyed, to view that files were added succeffuly to the list, i do like this: combo1.datasoure= list

Comment: @safi : yes, I believe you can by a List<> directly to a combobox, also : added a recursion sample

Comment: @Mr Eyes, Thanks alot and it did work for me. I was missing the recursive option, Now i am heading for the solution , thanks indeed. :)