# How to add files into List based on filename

Tags: c#, .net, file, for-loop, asp.net-core

I have files in a directory. I want to add each file to the list based on the filename in the loop. first need to sort based on code then value.

```
filename sample

   name|code|value|dept
   --------------------
   a_001_200_x.txt 
   ab_001_100_x.txt
   abc_003_100_x.txt
   abcd_002_100_x.txt
```

output should be

```
   a_001_100_x.txt
   ab_001_200_x.txt
   abc_002_100_x.txt
   abcd_003_100_x.txt
```

```
public void GetFiles()
{
     List<string> files =  Directory.GetFiles("C:/temp", "*.txt").ToList();
     foreach (var file in files)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a list of filenames from a folder in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795103/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-filenames-from-a-folder-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Is your question how to convert file name `a_001_200_x.txt` to `abc_001_200_x.txt` (and similar for other input file names)?

Comment: As pointed out by @Sinatr - your question is unclear.  Are you renaming files or sorting based on their existing name?

Comment: Unclear, `GetFiles()` is just a [`Directory.GetFiles(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_), no need for a loop here. For the second method, the sorting commenter the foreach loop. Everything look confusing. `AppendData`, but append  to what/where?

Comment: @Sinatr , I want to add files to the List based on sorting.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for you. Steps will be read filespaths then getonly filenames from filepaths. Then add them in the list. Orderby list by filename. Then read actual files with already order filepath. Hope this is clear. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
    //string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("Directory Path");
    string[] filePaths = new string[] { "a_001_200_x.txt", "ab_001_100_x.txt" };
    List<FileInput> fileInput = new List<FileInput>();
    foreach (string path in filePaths)
    {
        fileInput.Add(new FileInput
        {
           //here you can do Path.GetFileName(path).Substring(path.Length - 13, 13)
            FileName = path.Substring(path.Length - 13, 13),
            FilePath = path,
        });
    }

    fileInput = fileInput.OrderBy(x => x.FileName).ToList();

    foreach(var f in fileInput){
         //Read your file here from the disk with sorted order.
    }



public class FileInput
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: OK. I was thinking it will be fixed input 001_200 so considering it will be 13 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Tempfolder", "*.txt").ToList();

  var sortfiles = from file in files orderby Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToString().Split('_').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
         Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToString().Split('_').Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()
                 select file;


(Sample data )
   
   x_2_100_y.txt
   x_1_200_y.txt
   x_1_100_y.txt
   x_2_300_y.txt
   x_1_400_y.txt
   x_3_50_y.txt
   x_3_40_y.txt

(Sorting output (Ascending order))

  x_1_100_y.txt
  x_1_200_y.txt
  x_1_400_y.txt
  x_2_100_y.txt
  x_2_300_y.txt
  x_3_40_y.txt
  x_3_50_y.txt
```

Comment: So the "a[bcd]" part should be ignored? In your question, everything from "a" to "abcd" gets turned into "abc"...

Comment: @CodeCaster, Yes Correct. I just edited my question. All I need is need to sort files based on code and value.

Comment: Still doesn't match. Carefully look at your input and output.

Comment: it's still not clear abcd part need to ignored or considered for sorting? If you need to ignore abcd part then you can try my solution. It can be written if 2-3 lines I just wanted to give you an elaborated answer for understanding.

Comment: What if we have file name like  aa_001_200_x.txt   ab_001_100_x.txt  . How will that be sorted?

Comment: @Ingale88s, abcd part is ignored for sorting, only code and value fields are considered . I will try your solution.

Comment: @Ingale88s, as per my solution it will sort to ab_001_100_x.txt , aa_001_200_x

Comment: Great you got your solution.